# Need help wih \expandafter

Tags: expansion, plain-tex, optex

In OpTeX there is a macro `\addto` which adds some text to the definition of another macro. It is defined like this: `\long\def \addto #1#2{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}}`. Why are all those `\expandafter`s needed and especially what does the last one exactly do? As far as I understand, the last `\expandafter` takes away the `{`, then it expands `#1` and reinserts `{<expansion of #1>` into the token list. What about `#2`? How ist it expanded?

Comment: #2 is not expanded, it is simply appended to the content of #1.

Comment: after `\def\foo{abc}`, `\addo\foo{xyz}` is `\expandafter\def\expandafter\foo\expandafter{\foo xyz}` which is `\def\foo{abcxyz}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second argument is not expanded: let's follow

```
\def\aaa{x}
\addto\aaa{y}
```

The first definition is performed, then TeX expands `\addto` and it gets

```
\expandafter\def\expandafter\aaa\expandafter{\aaa y}
```

(the braces are stripped off by rule and there's no space after `\aaa`). This becomes

```
\def\aaa{xy}
```

as you wanted. If instead of `{y}` you had something like `\bbb` and you want to merge the contents of both `\aaa` and `\bbb` you need to do it like as follows

```
\def\aaa{x}
\def\bbb{y}
\expandafter\addto\expandafter\aaa\expandafter{\bbb}
```

After this the macro `\aaa` would expand to `xy`.

Comment: The last example is usable for cases when we want only first expansion of `\aaa` and `\bbb` to be saved to `\aaa`. Another case should be: we accept full expansion of `\aaa` and `\bbb` saved to `\aaa`. Then we can use simply `\edef\aaa{\aaa\bbb}`. If there is `\def\aaa{x}` and `\def\bbb{y}` (as in the mentioned example) then the result is the same.